# DB2: GRANT statement & access rights

Tags: sql, db2, sql-grant

What rights should I give to DB user to execute REFRESH TABLE SOME_MQT; statement? Is it enough GRANT ALL ON SOME_MQT TO USER %USER_NAME ?
DB2 version: 9.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for the REFRESH TABLE Statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000977.htm) seems pretty clear on that.

> The privileges held by the authorization ID of the statement must
>   include at least one of the following:
>
> - CONTROL privilege on the table
> - SYSADM or DBADM authority

I'm not sure whether GRANT ALL is enough. It's not unusual for a dbms to grant a subset of all possible privileges using GRANT ALL. But it's easy enough to test. Just GRANT ALL on a materialized view (not necessarily the view in question; use a scratch view) and let the user try to refresh it.